# Map inside fragment inside programmatically created view

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm working on an Android app with one activity which contains [stepper](https://material.google.com/components/steppers.html) with 3 steps. I've created a layout for each step and insert it programmatically in the scrollview in my activity. One step layout looks like this:

[image: Step layout]

The blue rectangle here is content which will be different in each step. First step should contain a map with the couple of buttons. I thought that it will be easier to make a fragment to work with the map outside the activity and just send data to activity when user finishes work with the map.

I insert each step to the activity with this code:

```
View step1, step2, step3; // they are global

//Inside onCreate:
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
FrameLayout mainView = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.stepper_container);

step1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_step, null);
parent.addView(step1);
step2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_step, null);
parent.addView(step2);
step3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_step, null);
parent.addView(step3);
setContentView(mainView);
```

I managed to successfully insert fragment with a map to the activity by creating a `<FragmentLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container" ... />"` in it and the following code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
OfficeMapFragment map = OfficeMapFragment.newInstance();
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, map);
transaction.commit();
```

But I can't do it with new programmatically added views as their elements' `id`'s are the same and when I change `id` parameter in transaction to the `id` of the "blue" container in step, app crashes with NullPointerException.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
```

`OfficeMapFragment` onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); // It crashes here
    return v;
}
```

## Q:

How to add the fragment inside one of the programmatically created views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved the problem:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    FrameLayout mainView = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.stepper_container);
    step1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_step, null);
    parent.addView(step1);
    // Other steps
    setContentView(mainView);
    FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) step1.findViewById(R.id.step_content_container);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    OfficeMapFragment map = OfficeMapFragment.newInstance();
    transaction.add(container.getId(), map);
    transaction.commit();
```

And it works fine (with minor layout bugs).

[image: Working map in the step]